How to change the font size and icon space of shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning?
Is there a way to change the font size of the warning message as well as the whitespace that is blocked for an icon inside the input prompt of textInput in shinyFeedback? In my shiny app, I have defined absolute widths for my textInput and when the warning message is triggered, the icon takes up space, even if I set it to icon=NULL, thereby cutting off the input. In addition, I'd really like to make the warning message smaller. Is there a way to do this through css in tags$head(tags$style())?
Minimal reproducible example:
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)

ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyFeedback::useShinyFeedback(),
        textInput("time", "Timestamp", 
                  value = '2024/04/01 00:00:00', 
                  width = '160px', placeholder = NULL)
))

server<- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe(shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning("time", 
                                         !(grepl('[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}', input$time)),
                                         "Please use a valid timeformat", 
                                         icon=NULL))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)

Edited to add a screenshot showing the whitespace allocated to the icon, even if set to Null


For changing the font size of the warning message and the space for the icon you can apply css such as
.form-group.shiny-input-container.has-feedback > div > p {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.has-feedback .form-control {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

Note that this gets applied to all inputs with a feedback.

If you on the other hand want to apply it only to specific inputs, you could act using ids:
#time-text > p {
  font-size: 10px;
}
#time { 
  padding-right: 20px;
}



The padding works, but the font size still doesn't work on my end. I'm not sure what I'm missing or if this is a version/system thing? I'm on macOS, but I did test jhk0530's code copy-pasted on a Windows PC as well, and both in R and RStudio.

Could you provide a minimal code with adjusted font size which not works?

Additionally: This is not version thing, I am also on macOS. Notice also that the code in the other answer can't work due to # shinyfeedback's text with id = time. This has to be /* shinyfeedback's text with id = time */, then it works. But this is not included in my answer, so the question is whether you changed anything.

Ok, I revisited this this morning. I had used your code, but just found out that for the font size tags$style(type="text/css", "#time-text > p {font-size: 10px;}") does not work, but tags$style(HTML("#time-text > p {font-size: 10px;}")) does. I'm trying to understand. I've been using tags$style(type="text/css",...) for the padding and that works fine. I had previously tried the other answer with tags$style(HTML(...)) and that didn't work either for the reason you explained above as I now know.

I didn't understand what do you mean about "Icon", so give more information will be good.
Anyway you can change shinyfeedback's text size with css as you mentioned.
See below (server is same)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyFeedback::useShinyFeedback(),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      #time-text > p { # shinyfeedback's text with id = time
        font-size: 10px;
      }
    "))
  ),
  textInput("time", "Timestamp",
    value = "2024/04/01 00:00:00",
    width = "160px", placeholder = NULL
  )
))



Thank you. For the icon, there is space allocated inside the input, even if the icon is set to Null. I'll update my original question to make this more clear.

Hm, I copy-pasted your answer and it's not actually changing the font size no matter what I set it to on my end?!
